# Yum update is not working properly in centos

Tags: centos, yum

Yum update is not working.I am not able to ping the external networks too

```
   yum update
   Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security
   Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
   Could not retrieve mirrorlist http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?   release=6&arch=x86_64&repo=os error was
  14: PYCURL ERROR 6 - "Couldn't resolve host 'mirrorlist.centos.org'"
   Error: Cannot find a valid baseurl for repo: base


      ping mirrorlist.centos.org
      ping: unknown host mirrorlist.centos.org
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure that your DNS settings are correctly configured. This can be done in two ways:

#### Method 1

1. Edit the interface configuration, using `vi /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0`
2. Change the settings to those of your network interface, thus change the DNS to suit your DNS.

   ```
   DEVICE=eth0
   BOOTPROTO=manual
   ONBOOT=yes
   IPADDR=10.0.1.27
   NETWORK=10.0.1.0
   NETMASK=255.255.255.0
   DNS=8.8.8.8
   ```

#### Method 2:

1. Use `vi /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0`.
   Add a new property `PEERDNS=no` as shown below:

   ```
   DEVICE=eth0
   BOOTPROTO=manual
   ONBOOT=yes
   IPADDR=10.0.1.27
   NETWORK=10.0.1.0
   NETMASK=255.255.255.0
   PEERDNS=no
   ```
2. Then `vi /etc/resolv.conf`

   Add DNS server (also referred to as nameserver) to `/etc/resolv.conf`:

   ```
   nameserver 8.8.8.8
   ```

   Finally, save the changes using `:wq`.

   Restart the service by typing `service network restart`.

Also, you might have to run tests to determine whether you are now able to connect to the internet; this can be done by performing ping tests:

1. Ping the gateway (tests IP and mask settings)
2. Ping google (tests DNS and default gateway settings)

Answer (score 0):

The error message `Couldn't resolve host 'mirrorlist.centos.org'` points to an issue with name resolution.

Try the command `host mirrorlist.centos.org`: if it fails, then that is the first problem to solve (check your DNS settings, and whether the machine is able to connect to the internet at all).

Comment: yes ..I m anot able to connect to the internet. host mirrorlist.centos.org
;; connection timed out; trying next origin
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached

Comment: How can can I resolve my DNS settings so that I can reach external network/internet

Comment: Can you access internet through your browser?